# Chrome extension using a background page + content scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the structure of Chrome extensions.

My extension has two different parts:

1. It uses a background page to log in via oAuth, then collates a lot of data from oAuth and saves it to `chrome.storage.local`.
2. When browsing webpages, it does a call to `chrome.storage.local` to check whether the current domain matches info stored from oAuth, and if so, displays a notification using the `[Rich Notifications API][1]`

The structure of my `manifest.json` is breaking things.

```
{
  "name": "API Test",
  "version": "3.1.2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "minimum_chrome_version": "29",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions": ["identity", "storage", "*://*/*"],
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "<<client_id>>",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
      "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["domchecker.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I do this, I get the following error from Chrome:

```
There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
'content_scripts' is only allowed for extensions and 
legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app.
```

Is it possible to do the two processes in tandem? If not, how can I use the background page to check for a page refresh and run a script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your manifest is an *app* manifest, as helpfully suggested by the error.

To fix, remove the `app` "wrapping", it should be just `background.scripts` key. Then it will be a valid extension manifest.

---

Of note: `chrome.notifications` is not available to content scripts; you'll need to use [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to request your background page to show it.

Comment: Indeed, I've tried removing the `app` "wrapping" but then I was unable to do my oauth logging in (which loads all of the data to `chrome.storage.local`). What do you suggest for this? Perhaps creating an icon app button to click to log in?

Comment: Sure, that would be a good idea. [`browserAction` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) will help you. Alternatively, if it's a one-time setup, you could just display an options page on first run.